# StreamBridge RabbitMQ Connection Denied on Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to follow the reference link (StreamBridge) and created a simple HTTP listener app that receives POST msg, validate incoming message with schema class & forward the request to RMQ. I am seeing **RMQ connection denied error** when I deploy the war (in CF) using SCDF. However, if I deploy the war using cf push, it works just fine. Do I have any additional RMQ configurations to do in StreamBridge WAR? I even compared env variables for RMQ Connection and it looks same in both the apps (SCDF deployed app & cf push app).

***org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AmqpOutboundEndpoint@6478a81c]; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[25], headers={contentType=application/json, id=9720e9cb-3fa1-1634-2e4c-55a24fa68c8b, timestamp=1619097558777}]] with root cause***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue with StreamBridge. No explanation I found for the different behavior on RMQ connection (cf push vs stream deployment) but by passing RMQ details (host, username, password and port) as arguments while creating a stream does the trick.

Link for reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_application_properties